# How do I handle this case for the following dynamic programming task?

Tags: dynamic-programming

I was attempting an easy level dp problem on topcoder which goes like this

> Petr and Snuke are playing a cooperative card game. The game is played
>   with special cards: each card is labeled with some positive integer.
>   The integers on cards are not necessarily distinct.
>
> At the beginning of the game Petr is holding some cards in his hand
>   and Snuke is holding all the other cards in his hand. You are given
>   int[]s petr and snuke that describe the state at the beginning of the
>   game: the elements of petr are the numbers on Petr's cards and the
>   elements of snuke are the numbers on Snuke's cards.
>
> During the game the players will place some of their cards onto a
>   pile. Initially, the pile is empty. The players take alternating
>   turns, Petr goes first. In each turn, if the current player has no
>   cards in his hand, the game ends. Otherwise, the player must make
>   exactly one valid move. There are three types of valid moves: If the
>   pile is empty, the player may choose any card and place it onto the
>   pile. If the pile is not empty, the player may choose any card and
>   place it on top of the pile. However, this move is only valid if the
>   number on the new card is strictly greater than the number on the card
>   that was previously on the top of the pile. The player may always
>   choose one of his cards and eat it.
>
> Petr and Snuke have a common goal: they want to create a pile with as
>   many cards as possible. Return the size of the pile at the end of the
>   game, assuming that they cooperate and play the game optimally.

I/O:

```
{2, 5}
{3, 1}
Returns: 3
One optimal way is as follows.
Petr puts 2 onto the pile.
Snuke puts 3 onto the pile.
Petr puts 5 onto the pile.
Snuke eats 1.
The game ends because Petr has no cards in his hand.

{1,1,1}
{1,1,1}
returns 1
```

I have defined a `dp` function defined as `dp[i][j]` be the maximum cards on the table at Petr's `ith` card and Snuke's `jth` card and tried out the following code:

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            if(i==0||j==0)
                dp[i][j]=1;
            else if(a[i]>b[j])
                dp[i][j] = max(dp[i-1][j]+1, dp[i][j-1]);
            else if(a[i]<b[j])
                dp[i][j]= max(dp[i-1][j], dp[i][j-1]+1);

            if(a[i]==b[j])
                dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j-1]; //This does not work
        }
    }
    cout <<  dp[2][2];
```

For simplicity I am just trying out for two elements. This solution works if the integers on cards are distinct. I am a bit confused to come up with non distinct case. What would be the definition of a `dp` state for equal integers?

Answer (score 0):

I think use should sort the elements of two player in increasing order first because of moving with smaller value always better than the bigger.

After that you dp:

F[i][j][u][v] is be the maximum cards on the table at Petr's i_th card and Snuke's u_th with {j,v}={0,1}: j=0 => Petr eats i_th card, 1=> Petr puts i_th onto the pie. The same with v for u.

Then

petr's turn: i>u:

F[i][0][u][v] = max(F[i-1][0][u][v], F[i-1][1][u][v]);

F[i][1][u][v] = max(F[i-1][0][u][v], F[i-1][1][u][v])+1;

Snuke's turn: i=u:

F[i][j][u][0] = max(F[i][j][u-1][0], F[i][j][u-1][1]);

F[i][j][u][1] = max(F[i][j][u-1][0], F[i][j][u-1][1])+1;

This is my idea, i haven't tried yet but i hope it will help you!